# Heroku Postgres hard limit on production mode?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, limit

As far as I know Heroku currently has hard limit of 1TB even on production DB. Is this true?

So why this limit is set and is there no way to over this limit? Or should I make multiple database instance and shard them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably Heroku just doesn't have database nodes configured with storage capacity for database sizes larger than that.  You should make multiple database instances and shard them.  If your database is much larger than that, though it might be time to look at alternatives to relational databases for some of your data types.  Sharding often discards some of the advantages of using SQL in the first place, at which point better-scaling alternatives start to look more attractive.

Comment: Yeah. Just after considering sharding, REDIS + eventual archiving looks a lot more attractive.

Comment: Redis has much more tight space restrictions than any other solution since it doesn't horizontally scale well and it's all in-memory.  It can still work if you are aggressive about archiving.  (Of course, anything can work if you are aggressive about archiving.)